# Vscode does not suggest imports when pressing CTRL + . but does suggest them during autocomplete when typing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When there is a Javascript module in my code that has not been imported yet, such as React's `useCallback`, highlightling `useCallback` and pressing CTRL+., Vscode does not suggest importing `useCallback`

However, if I were to type out `useCallback`, Vscode will suggest importing `useCallback`. I will expect pressing CTRL+. to do the same.

How can Vscode be configured so that pressing CTRL+. will suggest the import?

Using the following JS extensions

- [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)
- [IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode)
- [ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have extension ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets installed? (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets)

Also Ctrl + Space should suggest in my opinion

Comment: Yes I have it installed! I tried Ctrl + Space and selected `UseCallback   react` which imports `useCallback` as expected, but in my code `useCallback` has become something like `useCallbackack` depending on where the cursor is located when pressing Ctrl + Space

Comment: Vs code tries to autocomplete - so either your cursor should be at the end or you don't have it all typed up - so for useState - type useSta - then Ctrl Space. Also if you typed all characters already - Ctrl + right arrow to navigate end of word

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a related issue with VS Code not capturing Control + space shortcut properly on MacOS. If anyone has a similar one, please check your system keyboard shortcuts - in my case one of those was assigned this very combination, which resulted in VS Code not capturing it at all.

Hope I've helped :)

Comment: Thx man! That was it on a brand-new Mac. On your Mac, choose Apple menu > System Settings, click Keyboard in the sidebar (you may need to scroll down), then click Keyboard Shortcuts on the right.